# Setup for Linear Programming Problem : lpSolve in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

I need to solve a problem (reproducible toy example below):

There is a p matrix (N =3 x M=2):

```
p<-matrix(c(3,17,14,20,0,3), nrow=3, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
```

I seek to maximize the element-wise sum where lets say X is (3x2) and are binary variables:

[image]

The sum we are maximizing:
[image]

I have various constraints, the sum of each column of X are >= a. So, this would be written as (**EDIT: SHOULD BE >=**)

[image]

Another is that the rows of X need to be <= 1. This means that at most only a single X in a row can be activated (=1):

[image]

**Back to R**:

For the **objective function:**

**Question #1**: Do I need to "stretch" the p matrix into a vector:

```
obj<-c(3,17,14,20,0,3)
```

For the  **constraints:**

**Question #2** Does the constraint matrix need to be sized (rows= number of constraints, columns = number of x's in X)?

So for these constraints, it would be `(5,6)`?

**Question #3**

Would the constraint matrix look like this - assuming I am correct about Question #2?

[image]

The first row represents `x11 + x21 + x31 >= a1`

The second row represents `x12 + x22 + x32 >= a2`

The third row represents `x11 + x12 <=1`

The fourth row represents `x21 + x22 <=1`

The fifth row represents `x31 + x32 <=1`

Then of course the direction matrix and the RHS matrix are set accordingly.

Comment: See ?lp.transport

Comment: Not sure I see the connection I am afraid. If you happen to know if my setup / understanding for lpSolve is correct I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, I see now that my problem is a transportation problem. I did not however provide sufficient information, in that I have one additional constraint which is that the grand sum of the rows and columns of X (which are binary variables) need to be <= T. It does not appear this can fit into the transportation problem framework.